# Creative difficulty "ascension level" options

Tags: game-design, roguelikes, difficulty

I'm making a roguelike (not a deck builder though) heavily inspired by slay the spire. I'm looking to flesh out my ascension style difficulty levels with creative and interesting penalties for the player.

What are some games with ascension level style difficulties that have some creative penalties that I can take inspiration from? Basically, I don't want to just give my enemies more dmg/hp.

Comment: "List some games you think I should look at" is a little broad and opinion-based for the format we use here. Can you edit your question to describe the specific mechanics of your game in more detail, and the criteria you're trying to meet for your ascension levels? Then users here can suggest bespoke options that help solve the problem in your game. [See the tag guidance on the game-design tag for more tips on crafting focused on-topic game design questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/game-design/info),

Comment: I agree it would be beneficios for you to see more of these games. And while I suppose some people around are probably aware of some mechanically interesting ones, we have no have no way to know if they are at all useful for you. So, what I would suggest instead is to go see what are the popular ones according to whatever and work your way down the list.

Comment: You might also want to edit your question to define what exactly you mean with "ascension style". Remember that not everyone played every game in existence, so defining something as "Just like in [game]" will exclude a lot of people from answering which might be able to give you useful input if you had explained what you need in your own words.